# Anonymous User name is changed to a strange name in watchdog logs

Tags: users

Our D9 site's dblog is showing the anonymous user name as a very stange name instead of anonymous. All anonymous users are shown as "closhewupheheh…" even though the anonymous user name is set to "Anonymous" in the account settings.

I suspect this may be related to the "realname" module but there is nothing in the issue queues related to the anonymous user name.

Is this anything to be concerned about?

Is there a way to get it to display "Anonymous" again?

[image]

Comment: If you suspect it's the Realname module, from a dev copy of the site, uninstall the module and see if the problem recurs. I've used Realname on several sites and never seen anything like that.  Also, if the site is translated, check the translations.

Comment: Thank you, Patrick. I've uninstalled the Real Name and Name Field modules but the strange anonymous name is still in the logs. Really baffled now as to the cause.

Comment: I had this happen on a D9 site and reset back to defaults with drush.
`drush sql-query "UPDATE users_field_data SET preferred_admin_langcode=NULL, name='', mail=NULL, timezone='', status=0, created=0, changed=0, access=0, login=0 WHERE uid=0";`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the root cause was but I ended up updating the user account's DB entry to change it back to Anonymous. Resolved.